# Aggregated Columns in Pandas within a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm creating columns with aggregated values with the data from Pandas Dataframe using groupby() and reset_index() functions like that:

```
df=data.groupby(["subscription_id"])["count_boxes"].sum().reset_index(name="amount_boxes")

df1=data.groupby(["subscription_id"])["product"].count().reset_index(name="count_product")
```

Want to combine all these aggregated columns ("amount_boxes" and "count_product") in one dataframe with groupby column "subscription_id". Is there any way to do that ithin a function rather than merging the dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at using `.agg` with a dictionary of column and aggregation function.

```
(df.groupby('Subscription_id')
   .agg({'count_boxes':'sum','product':'count'})
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={'count_boxes':'amount_boxes','product':'count_product'}))
```

Sample Output:

```
   Subscription_id  amount_boxes  count_product
0                1            16              2
1                2            39              6
2                3            47              7
```